# Free silent movie card font

Tags: fonts, font-recommendation, open-source

I am looking for a font that looks like it could come from a silent movie text card.

I'd like to use this font in an open-source application, so the font itself needs to be open-source and free to share. Anything from Google Fonts or Open Font Library would work.

Something like the following:

[image: https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/0fea7a17292449.562b82372a000.png]

[image: https://i2.wp.com/moviessilently.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/haunted-spooks-harold-lloyd-image-1.jpg]

Comment: Have you tried looking through the retro or serif categories at dafont(dot)com. Many of their fonts have free licences.

Answer (score 3):

It is not a serif, but [Josefin Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Josefin+Sans) from Google Fonts has a vintage quality that to me seems appropriate:

[image: Josefin Sans]

[Smythe](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Smythe) also from Google might work:

[image: Smythe]

Comment: p.s. In googling why Smythe's type designer is no longer active, I found out of his untimely death, leaving wife and kids. Although I've never used Smythe, some of his other fonts have been very useful (Trocchi, Pacifico, François one, Amatic, Antonio and specially Oswald)... damn 

Comment: Thanks for the font recommendations. In the end, I found that Sanchez and Cutive work really well for me.